# Angular JS handle password encryption

Tags: angularjs, password-encryption, password-hash

I need your help. What is the best way to handle password encryption in a angular js app?

In my case I have an php server what serves the data to my app. Now we want to implement a possibility for users to log in.

I was asked if angular can handle phps password_hash().

Now the big question is, what is the best way to handle such a case.

Thanks for your answers.

Dominic

Comment: yeah why not. u can use the bcrypt-Algorithmus (witch can be used with password_hash) also with angularjs (JavaScript).

Comment: Look into JWT (JSON Web Tokens)